# Using a zener diode and a bjt to regulate voltage received by a controller

Tags: microcontroller, voltage-regulator, diodes, bjt, zener

Okay, here goes…

I’m trying to create a circuit that will prevent low conductance (from rain water exposure) which occasionally shorts a particular switch, from triggering a controller input that the switch is sent to. The controller input needs to see ONLY voltages of 9-12V, but the rain water is causing a conductance of ~3V. — The controller sends a 12V signal that is read by the input when the switch is closed — So, I am trying to create a circuit that will output 3V only when the switch conductance is at minimum 9V+.

I’m including a screenshot of a circuit I think could work. I was having a slight problem during testing, which is difficult for me to explain because of my lack of knowledge/experience. But I think I might be simulating the partial conductance incorrectly. So, I’m only asking if you think this circuit should work for the intended purpose… or if something else might do the job better.

Hopefully all that made sense. Thanks for any advice. Please be gentle!

[image: --]

***---------* Edit *---------***

I am adding a hand-drawn diagram to try to clear up some vagueness my original post might've had. I may have used slightly incorrect terminology, so apologies for that. But what I'm basically trying to accomplish is to keep the voltage received by the controller well below 3V until the switch is essentially closed, as opposed to just getting moisture across its terminals.

Going forward, the the switch will be replaced. However, this fix is more for the field... like if somebody had the device and needed to just add a simple attachment to it to correct the issue, without going to a shop to get it serviced.

[image: --]

Comment: The input is tied to 12 V rail so your controller will always "see" 12 V at the input.

Comment: The output is fixed at 12V, also, you shouldnt leave the base of the transistor floating, when the switch is open the base should be grounded through a resistor. The BJT acts as an inverter, so in your circuit, with the switch open, the output at the collector of the BJT is around 12V, when the switch closes it is at aprox. 0V

Comment: @LongPham What if the input is moved below the 1k resistor? I may have drawn it incorrectly.

Comment: What's the purpose of the Zener? What do you mean by "conductance of ~3V"? I think a block diagram of what you're trying to achieve here might help.

Comment: If you move your output to below the resistor, when the switch is closed the output will go close to ground.  When the switch is open, who knows?  You have left the base floating.  Connect a resistor from the base to ground so the transistor turns off when the switch is open.

Comment: @evildemonic Okay, so maybe I should connect the emitter of the transistor to the input of the controller instead? And of course connect the base to ground, like you said.

Comment: @PeteJones If you want 'positive logic' switching, yes.  You would still want a pull-down so your output goes low when the switch is open.  In this case, you will want both a resistor on your output to ground, and a resistor on the NPN's base to ground.  All this is assuming I even know what you are talking about...I would edit your question to be more clear exactly what you are trying to do.  Where are you getting this 3V output, for example?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "conductance of ~3V"? conductance is measured in siemens, not volts.

Comment: How about fixing that switch?

Comment: What is the resistor from +12V to GND for?

Comment: Your hand drawn schematic still has all the problems discussed in this comment section.  And now you have the base of the transistor shorted to ground...this will never work.

Comment: 1. I don't see why there's a resistor from +12V to ground, unless it's a heater.  2.  As mentioned, the circuit's not going to get the intended result.  3.  Why not just connect a resistor from the "input" line to ground?  That should hold the "input" line down with more authority, and you can experiment with the resistor value to find something that works without burning out the switch (I suspect you have a **lot** of leeway).

Comment: If you can, measure the amount of current that's leaking when the switch is wet, or disconnect a wet switch from the circuit and measure it's resistance.  Post that -- it'll help to ground (as it were) the discussion.

Comment: Terms to search in google: "NEMA 3R enclosure".  And also "IP67 switch."

Comment: From the added circuit in the picture, your base is shorted to the emitter, thus your transistor will never switch on since $V_{be} = 0V$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mentioned my problem to a teacher, who told me about an op amp that I wasn't aware existed, the LM339. Apparently, arranged like this will produce the desired result (a simple voltage divider can be used to calculate the values of R1 and R2):

Output Inacticve:
[image: Output Inactive]

Output Active:
[image: Output Active]

Anyway, thanks for the comments and suggestions! I guess I just had the wrong idea to begin with, which is what I was afraid of. I think it was [@evildemonic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/121030/evildemonic) who mentioned a comparator, which hit the nail on the head.